# Using map vs DTO in spring-boot applicatoin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

What is preferred way to accept POST request data in spring-boot application:
either to use a map(key,value) pair to map the post request's body or use a DTO to map the request content.

If someone can elicit the pros and cons of each it will be really helpful.

Code Snippet for same-
Using map:

```
@PostMapping("/updateBalance")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateBalance(RequestEntity<List<Map<String, Object>>> requestData,HttpServletRequest headerRequest)
```

Using DTO:

```
@PostMapping("/updateBalance")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateBalance(List<RequestDTO> requestData,HttpServletRequest headerRequest)
```

Answer (score 7):

If the format of your incoming data is fixed (ie always has the same data items), you use a DTO. This allows to fail fast if the expected format is not matched.

If the incoming data has variable entries, you can use a map and pluck it apart to put the individual items however they need to be handled.

Answer (score 1):

DTO by convention does the work of data transference from the through the different layers of the data flow . Why would you need to use a Map in this place ?? Better to use a DTO than a HashMap to skip the overhead of the parsing the Map

Answer (score 0):

Maps have only one advantage - universality, no any specific implementations, used in any controllers/services/etc. That's all.
With DTO you can customize the process of serialization and deserialization. And if usually this process is very simple -  DTO field <-> json field, then sometime with DTA you can implement specific deserialization action (json string value to enum) or in specific way handle a value. Also, DTO can have specific interaction between json field names and object field names, specific order. With DTO much easier to use field validations, and only with DTO you can use specific messaging in validation process.
I see plenty of advantages in using DTO.